# Cannot map the 'Window' key of a window keyboard of IKBC KB87

Tags: keyboard

I am not sure if it is a generic behaviour or merely a problem with this particular keyboard.

I have used the eventviewer of karabinar to check.

[image] Pressing the left or right window do not register any event at all.

OSX recognise the keyboard as ANSI

[image]

Here is a photo of the keyboard:

[image]

and here is the [link to the product](http://www.ikbc.com.tw/copy-of-kd104).

What is the likely cause of the issue? The hardware key event is not firing or osx is not registering the window key?

Comment: For me the window key, by default has always triggered Left Command. Have you been able to use the windows key with any other keyboard? — Maybe you were using Karabiner just to see the output of the key, but just so you know, you can set modifier keys without 3rd party applications from [`System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard (first tab) > Modifier Keys...`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4a4p.png).

Comment: Saw the lock icon in the windows key and because my gaming keyboard has a separate key that will disable the windows key (a feature mostly seen in gaming keyboards), I started googling. Your keyboard also has this feature and apparently the windows key lock is toggled with [`Fn + Windows key`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdRXN.png). So maybe try that.

Comment: @Joonas YOU * ARE * MY * HERO! By hitting Fn + Right Window Key, it unlocks the window key! Please kindly convert your comment into an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyboard has a windows key lock feature that is turned on.

In this particular keyboard the toggle switch for windows key lock is `Fn + Windows key`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdRXN.png]

The trigger for windows key lock may be different in other keyboards.